# How to fix Invalid customer address id in Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, shipping-methods

How to fix Invalid customer address id 1678 etc when trying to add to cart in Magento 2.1.5

It was fixed before by adding a foreign key field to "customer_address_id".

After adding the matrixrate module its showing the same error.

Comment: This issue is fixed by giving below command but how to fix it permanently 

UPDATE `quote_address` SET `customer_address_id`=NULL
WHERE 
`customer_address_id` NOT IN (
SELECT `entity_id`
FROM `customer_address_entity`
WHERE parent_id = `quote_address`.customer_id
)
;

Comment: I get still same issue when upgrade site from 2.2 to 2.3 is there any update?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is known by Magento,

The problem was in the file: `app/code/Magento/Persistent/Model/QuoteManager.php`

It has been corrected in `2.3.4-p2`.

But otherwise the bug was a bit "random".

Here is the conversation around the bug: [Issue 23618](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23618).

Otherwise, You can fix orphelin adresse by doing this :

`UPDATE quote_address SET customer_address_id=NULL WHERE customer_address_id NOT IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM customer_address_entity WHERE parent_id = quote_address.customer_id )`

Good luck